# Custom Activity Data Binding with Salesforce Objects

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity, databinding

We can't extract data from the incoming Salesforce Object in the Journey Builder to the Custom Activity we made. We have already followed the syntax that was instructed in your documentation -> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm (under Event Context section).

We are primarily using Postmonger for our Custom Activity, and in our `config.json` under the `inArguments`, we input something like below to fetch the data from the Salesforce Object:

```
"fieldKey": "{{Event." + [ eventDefinitionKey ] + ".Task:Field_Name__c}}"
```

The `eventDefinitionKey` we get from the data loaded by triggering the `requestedTriggerEventDefinition` exposed by the Postmonger.

The resulting inArguments from above would be something like this:

```
"fieldKey": "{{Event.SalesforceObjacf28b016bf83c75b4926e0ec292eda5.Task:SMS_Content__c}}"
```

And based from the documentation mentioned previously, that syntax should be enough, yet we cannot retrieve it on our Custom Activity.

Another thing to note is that we can fetch information using the same syntax if the entry object is a Data Extension like below:

```
"fieldKey": "Event.DEAudience-e56d43c3-e2cf-60f1-fecd-ecf4d358d7b4.Field_Name"
```

The syntax above work which uses Data Extension is okay, but the one with the Salesforce Object does not.

What are we doing incorrectly here or is not possible entirely?

NOTE: the journey gets triggered by creating a task in Service Cloud

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted, so others can easily see this has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Salesforce Entry Events, this is a bit different and you need to add double quotes around the path/column name to the field. So for your case this should look like this:

```js
"fieldKey": "{{Event." + eventDefinitionKey + ".\"Task:Field_Name__c\"}}"
```

which should result in:

```js
{{Event.SalesforceObjacf28b016bf83c75b4926e0ec292eda5."Task:SMS_Content__c"}}
```

For reference you might like to look at an example custom activity I put on my github account: [Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Service Cloud Custom Split Activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)